# Converting raw laravel mysql json query into postgres syntax

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, postgresql

I have the following query that works in MYSQL

```
$query->whereRaw('
    ST_Distance_Sphere(
      point(address->>"$.longitude", address->>"$.latitude"),
      point(?, ?)
    ) * .000621371192 < ?
', [$longitude, $latitude, $distance]);
```

When i deployed to heroku im getting this error

> SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "$.longitude" does not exist
> LINE 3:           point(address->>"$.longitude", address->>"$.latitu...

Im using postgres on heroku and i know the issue is something to do with the json operator.

What is the `$.<json key>` syntax called? and how do i convert this raw sql query to postgres?

In the worse case i leaning on switching my database to mysql if i cant solve this by Wednesday as it wont be a big deal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres uses double quotes as delimiter for columns, so you must use single quotes to indicate strings. Laravel will take care of it

```
st_distance_sphere(
    st_point(address->>'$.longitude',address->>'$.latitude'),st_point(?, ?)
)
```